# Update all rows in a table serially in a single update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table looks like this

```
Serial   |  Name   | Age
------------------------
   1     |  Aby    | 43
   3     |  Philip | 15
   5     |  Tom    | 65
   6     |  Jacob  | 33
   7     |  Matt   | 13
   11    |  Jerom  | 37
```

---

I need to update this table such a way that all the valus in **serial** column must be continues without any missing values like this

```
Serial   |  Name   | Age
------------------------
   1     |  Aby    | 43
   2     |  Philip | 15
   3     |  Tom    | 65
   4     |  Jacob  | 33
   5     |  Matt   | 13
   6     |  Jerom  | 37
---------------------------
```

How can I achieve this in a single **update query**

Comment: Let me guess `IDENTITY` column. What with foreign keys?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You really should store date of birth instead of age

Comment: I hope it isn't used as foreign key somewhere else

Comment: @Mihai Actually its not a new table. I've been asked to modify a system in which  the old data using a serial column. But when a row deletes the serial also got removed. But some old data having lots of broken serials which I was trying to fix using some methods in a cursor..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
;with T as (
  select row_number () over (order by Serial) as RN, *
  from yourtable
)
update T
set Serial = RN
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

1. Create a new table with the same structure but with a `Primary Key Identity`:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Z_NEW_TABLE](
       [SERIAL] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [NAME] [varchar](MAX) NULL,
       [AGE] [INT] NULL
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Z_NEW_TABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [SERIAL] ASC
   )WITH (
       PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   ```
2. Insert your data in the new table

   ```
   INSERT INTO Z_NEW_TABLE (NAME, AGE)
   SELECT NAME, AGE
   FROM Z_OLD_TABLE
   ```
3. At the end drop the old table and rename new table

Comment: If `Serial` is identify column, this is preferred way. Otherwise, there is no way to update identify column.

Comment: @qxg, set identity isert on

Answer (score 1):

```
    create table #tmp ( id int, name varchar(100)).

insert into #tmp
select 1,'Kesavan'
union
select 3,'Suyambu'
union
select 5,'Mani'
union 
select 7,'Mahesh'
```

You need to declare some variable to achieve this,

```
declare @Count int =1
update #tmp set  @count = id =@count+1 where id != @count
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the update -

```
CREATE TABLE #updatetable (Serial int,  Name  varchar(10), Age int)
insert into #updatetable
select   1,       'Aby',     43 union all
select      3,       'Philip',  15 union all
   select   5 ,      'Tom',     65 union all
   select   6  ,     'Jacob',   33 union all
   select   7   ,    'Matt'  ,  13 union all
   select   11   ,   'Jerom'  , 37
update #updatetable
set Serial = rn
from (
select Serial,row_number() over(order by Serial) rn 
from #updatetable
) a
inner join #updatetable b on a.Serial = b.serial
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP. Answer from newbie:

```
$first_data =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$total = mysql_num_rows();
if($total > 0){
for($i=1; $i <= $total; $i++){
$fd = mysql_fetch_array($first_data);
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET serial='".$i."' WHERE Name='".$fd['Name']."'");
}
}
```